# What happens with an automatically caught exception?

Tags: php, exception, handler

Suppose one has the following code:

```
try {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 10) {
        if ($i == 7) {
            throw new Exception("Test exception");
        }
        $i++;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
print($i);
```

This will return `7`. When the first Exception in the try block is caught, the program will execute the catch block and then carry on below that block(, not?).

However, what happens when I set an automatic exception handler (with `set_exception_handler()`)? When I run this code, I don't get a return value:

```
function the_handler($e) {
}
set_exception_handler('the_handler');
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    if ($i == 7) {
        //throw new Exception("Test exception");
    }
    $i++;
}
print($i);
```

Why is that? What exactly happens after the call to the exception handler?

Comment: `set_exception_handler()` does not 'catch' exceptions, it defines PHP's behaviour after an *uncaught* exception is encountered. Usually this means failing gracefully and not showing the user a stack trace full of data that you might not want made public.

Comment: @Sammitch yes, that's my bad, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) says:

> Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

See the discussion on the manual page for a lot of special cases, e.g. when you throw an exception in the exception handler.

Comment: Huh, I totally missed that. Apologies! (I guess there's no workaround?)

Comment: @CamilStaps IMO it does not make sense to provide a workaround, since how to handle an exception is specific to the flow where it is thrown. The `try...catch` construct is a much better tool to recover from exceptions.

Comment: @gzm0 whole heartedly agree... this just lets you do the wrong thing easily (pokemon exception handling)